# How to update a text value in a button

Tags: python, kivy

i'm new to python and kivy and I have trouble to display updated value from a variable

```
Class DButton(Button):
    def on_press(self):
        MyApka.moneyy = MyApka.moneyy - 10
        Button(text=str(MyApka.moneyy))
        if(MyApka.moneyy < 10):
            print('you dont have money')
```

For now is only displaying the starting value which it is 100.
There is a code in which I'm decreasing the value of "MyApka.moneyy" by 10 when I click and I want to get this variable "MyApka.moneyy" to be displayed and updated each click I click.

```
class MyApka(App):
    #moneyy = StringProperty('100')
    moneyy = 100     
    

    def build(self):        
        self.load_kv('my.kv')
        return
```

```
<MyTApka>
      DButton:
            size_hint_x: 0.1
            size_hint_y: 0.1
            pos_hint: {'right': 0.3}
            text: str(app.moneyy)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you make the `moneyy` attribute into a `Property`, the `Button` will get updated automatically when you change the `moneyy` value.

So, in your `App` code:

```
class MyApka(App):
    moneyy = NumericProperty(100)
    # moneyy = 100
```

Then your `DButton` class can modify that `Property` by accessing the `App`:

```
class DButton(Button):
    def on_press(self):
        app = App.get_running_app()
        app.moneyy = app.moneyy - 10
        # Button(text=str(MyApka.moneyy))
        if(app.moneyy < 10):
            print('you dont have money')
```